# Problems when dropping levels in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a subset of a data frame and then dropped all the levels. However, at the end, my subseted data frame ended with just 1 (ones).

I created a subset of a data frame that looks like:

```
dfsubset <- df[5, ]
  X1      X2        X3       X4          X5                 X6         X7                    
  NA    Name     Series No Category Series Name    Series Description Unit
```

However, when I checked the newly created data set I found that there were a lot of levels:

```
str(dfsubset)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ X1 : num NA
 $ X2 : Factor w/ 3 levels "xxxx","xxxxx",..: 3
 $ X3 : Factor w/ 171 levels "1","10","100",..: 171
 $ X4 : Factor w/ 21 levels "xxxx","xxxx",..: 4
 $ X5 : Factor w/ 172 levels "xxxxxx",..: 132
 $ X6 : Factor w/ 172 levels "xxxxxxx",..: 138
 $ X7 : Factor w/ 36 levels "%","Â±%","Binary",..: 36
```

Therefore, I used the `droplevels` function hoping that my dataframe will just remain with the info I needed (Name, Series No, Category, Series Name, Series Description, Unit)

However, my data frame ended up with just 1 (ones)

```
    dfsubset <- droplevels(dfsubset)     
str(dfsubset)
     $ X1 : num NA
     $ X2 : Factor w/ 1 level "Utility": 1
     $ X3 : Factor w/ 1 level "Series No": 1
     $ X4 : Factor w/ 1 level "Category": 1
     $ X5 : Factor w/ 1 level "Series Name": 1
     $ X6 : Factor w/ 1 level "Series Description": 1
     $ X7 : Factor w/ 1 level "Unit": 1
```

Now, I try to use the new data frame with the levels dropped in the function `names(df) <- subsetdf` and what I get is just ones in the column names.

How can I end up with a data frame that contains the info I need (Name, Series No, Category, and so on) instead of just 1 (ones) to use in the `names(df) <- subsetdf` function?

Comment: did you print the data, seems like however you read in the data you should have used `header = TRUE`

Comment: I read the data using the read.xlsx function. However, the info I need as a header is not in the first row but in other row (it changes as I am reading several .xlsx files, it could be in the 2nd, 3rd, 10th). The files have a lot of noise.

Comment: Why are you dropping the levels?  Are you intending to convert the factor to character?

Comment: I thought that would be the best way of getting rid of all the info I did not need and just leave the info I needed (Utility, Series No, Category, and so on)

Comment: @dcgodoyg read.xlsx has a parameter (`startRow`) so you can start reading data at a specific row

Comment: @rawr Thank you! I would consider that! Although I dont know how efficient is to open a file, find where the header is, close the file, and then open the file again specifying the row that contains the header (almost 100 files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  dfsubset <- sapply( df[5, ] , as.character)
```